# Fig / Docker-Compose-like JSON to feed into Mesosphere/Marathon to setup Multi-Tier Application

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

Does anyone know if it is possible to setup a JSON file to feed into Mesosphere/Marathon to deploy multi-tier application with application dependency? Something along the lines of **fig** or **docker compose** when there is one yaml file describing applications to deploy and their dependency and etc ?

Thanks!!

Alex

Comment: Yes and this is a very timely question since I'm putting together a walkthrough on this, as we speak ;) for the time being you might want to check out https://github.com/mhausenblas/ntil which goes a bit in this direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see [Application Deployments](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/deployments.html). I'm in the process of extending the Marathon doc to make this even clearer. Will provide updates here as well.

Comment: Thank you! ETA: next couple of days.

Comment: Mike, yet again, thanks for all the work. Small question: the Application Deployment section where you have a sample syntax for the application group: is it supposed to go against DCOS (i.e., "dcos marathon app add test.json") or just feed it to marathon directly via API call ("cat test.json |  http http:\\<>:8080...etc) ? Because for "dcos marathon app add..." it is complaining on: "Error: Additional properties are not allowed ('groups' was unexpected)"

Comment: It's a (current) CLI limitation, yes so please use directly the HTTP API for now, sorry.